# QBPrivateChatManager getting null

Tags: android, quickblox

I am getting QBPrivateChatManager as null , I am using following code :

```
    QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getIntance();
    privateChatManager = chatService.getPrivateChatManager();
```

getting privateChatManager as null.

Comment: `QBChatService.getIntance();` should be `QBChatService.getInstance();`

Comment: Yes, I have used the same, that was typo mistake.

Comment: are you logged in if your are not logged in then `chatService.getPrivateChatManager();` will be null.

Comment: Yes It was login issue thanks

Answer (score 3):

You must to create User session first

```
 QBAuth.createSession(new QBUser("garrysantos", "garrysantospass"), new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {
        // success
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
        // errors
    }
});
```

See more : http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Answer (score 0):

```
chatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
```

is null if you're not logged in ti Chat

so you have to login to chat first and then call this method

Comment: I use already login method and check isInitialized.if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
     QBChatService.init(ctxxx);
     chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
    }